# Missing header information in a java TCP socket using HTTP

Tags: java, sockets, http, tcp, http-headers

I'm doing a request with Google Advanced rest client (ARC) and I receive the following response:

```
date: Sat, 11 Nov 2017 15:33:16 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html
```

I have to develop a TCP socket in java that sends a request using HTTP in the application layer and send the same request as in the google ARC. This is the code that I'm using:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class tcpclient {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        if (argv.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("java server");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket socket;

        InetAddress address;

        byte[] mensaje_bytes = new byte[256];

        String mensaje = "";

        try {
            address = InetAddress.getByName(argv[0]);
            socket = new Socket(address, 80);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true);


            String message = "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                    + "Host: somehost\r\n"
                    + "User-agent: someuser\r\n"
                    + "\r";

            out.println( message );

            do {
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
            } while (in.readLine() != null);

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the above code I'm receiving the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 0
```

I would like to know why I have some missing headers lines like for example allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling in.readLine() twice per iteration, and only print one of the read lines.

Comment: :( thanks @JBNizet. I changed the iteration and now it works `String responseLine;
            while ((responseLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(responseLine);
            }`